# Interchange of order of integration for $\int_0^\infty y^{s-1} e^{-ay} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2yx)\cos(\pi x^2)}{\sinh(\pi x)}dx dy $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, laplace-transform

I have been trying to interchange the order of integration for the integral: $$\int_0^\infty y^{s-1} e^{-ay} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2yx)\cos(\pi x^2)}{\sinh(\pi x)}dx dy $$

I am unable to find a proof for the same. Using Mathematica I was able to see that the values are the same even when we interchange the order of integration upto some $s,a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a>0$.

But for larger values of $s$, mathematica says it is divergent, so I am interested in the condition on $s,a$ such that we can interchange the order of integration.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you have having trouble interchanging the order of integration (which doesn't really depend on the function your integrating)? Or are you having trouble learning properties of the integral after interchanging the order of integration? Those are very different questions.

Comment: @MarkS. I am having trouble interchanging the order of integration. Then the second thing I want to look into is the possible values of "a" and "s" such that the integral is finite. Right now I am concerned about how to interchange the order.

Comment: @MarkS. Can you please suggest me how can I interchange the order?